# How to Stream API multiple groupBy presents data with Map<expressions, Object>?

Tags: java, java-stream

In C# with linq, the code below for rawdata defining by Enumerable

`var data = rawdata.GroupBy(x => new { x.getSurname, x.getBirthYear });`

presents 
`IEnumarable<IGrouping<'a, Person>>`

`'a is new {String Person.Surname, String Person.BirthYear}`

and then I try convert this to Spring Java with same query by Stream API;

```
var data = rawdata.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getSurname, Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getBirthYear)));
```

in this line, 'data' will be
`Map<String, Map<String, List<Person>>>`

The first one is Surname and the second one in sub-map is BirthYear.

I think, Stream Api's groupBy not present data like linq in C#.

Is there a way for the code above presents `Map<a, List<Person>>`, a to be type including `{String x, String y}` that is from groupBy expressions?

Comment: Isn't `Map<String, Map<String, List<Person>>>` what you want? Short of defining your own Map Key-Class for `a`?

Comment: Yes, it is. But I want to ```Map<'a, List<Person>>``` that 'a to be type including {String x, String y}. I think @Eran understood. And helped very well. The code at the bottom works for me. You can check this, below.

Comment: Alright. If you are happy with @Eran 's solution please accept his answer and upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by either concatenating the name and year of birth and group by the concatenated `String`, or creating a class having these 2 properties, and creating an instance of that class for group by.

```
var data = 
    rawdata.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getSurname() + "-" + p.getBirthYear()));
```

or

```
var data = 
    rawdata.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> new GroupByClass(p.getSurname(),p.getBirthYear())));
```

The latter requires defining `GroupByClass`, which must override `equals` and `hashCode` in order to be able to group the `Person` instances correctly.

Another option is to create a `List` of the `String`s you wish to group by:

```
var data = 
    rawdata.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> List.of(p.getSurname(), p.getBirthYear())));
```

The second alternative is the most type safe way, but requires creating the additional class.

Comment: Yes, it worked for me. Thank you Eran for very helpful comment.